# Why do characters span the space of class functions?

Tags: soft-question, finite-groups, representation-theory, intuition, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\chi_1, \dotsc, \chi_t$ be a complete collection of irreducible complex characters of $G$ with corresponding representations $V_1, \dotsc, V_t$ (i.e. every irreducible complex representation of $G$ is isomorphic to precisely one of the $V_i$).

> I am searching for some intuition behind the following statement:
>
> *The characters $\chi_1, \dotsc, \chi_t$ span $C(G)$, the space of complex-valued class functions on $G$*.

(One could also take all characters of $G$ instead of only the irreducible ones without changing the question.)

There seem to be two standard proofs for this statement, but none of them helped me get a better understanding of the problem so far.
(I have included both of them below.)

Is also suspect that my lack of intuition may come from a lack of understanding  of *what class functions actually are*.
While I tend to think about them as central elements of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$, I’m not sure how well this works when it comes to characters.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**The two proofs**

- One can identify $C(G)$ with the center $\operatorname{Z}(\mathbb{C}[G])$ as vector spaces. (For some people these are already the same.)
  From $\mathbb{C}[G] \cong \prod_{i=1}^t M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ (with $n_i = \dim V_i$) it then follows that
  $$
          \operatorname{Z}(\mathbb{C}[G])
    \cong \operatorname{Z}\left( \prod_{i=1}^t M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C}) \right)
    =     \prod_{i=1}^t \operatorname{Z}( M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C}) )
    \cong \prod_{i=1}^t \mathbb{C},
  $$
  so $\dim C(G) = t$.
  Since $\chi_1, \dotsc, \chi_t$ are linearly independent (because they are orthonormal) they already span $C(G)$.

The gist of this proof is that dimensions match up, but it doesn’t really seem to explain why they should do so in the first place.

- Since $\chi_1, \dotsc, \chi_t$ are orthonormal it sufficies to show that every $\alpha \in C(G)$ which is orthogonal to every $\chi_i$ vanishes.
  This is equivalent to $\beta \in C(G)$ with $\beta(g) = \alpha(g^{-1})$ vanishing, which in turn is equivalent to the central element $\hat{\beta} := \sum_{g \in G} \beta(g) g \in \operatorname{Z}(\mathbb{C}[G])$ being zero.
  This holds iff the map $\mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}[G]$, $x \mapsto \hat{\beta} x$ vanishes.
  This map is $G$-equivariant because $\hat{\beta}$ is central, and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations, each of which is invariant under $\hat{\beta}$;
  it therefore sufficies to show that for every irreducible representation $V_i$ the $G$-equivariant map
  $$
    f_i \colon V_i \to V_i,
    \quad
            v
    \mapsto \hat{\beta}{.}v
    =       \sum_{g \in G} \beta(g) g{.}v
  $$
  vanishes.
  By Schur’s Lemma the map $f_i$ is given by multiplication with $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$, and since
  $$
      n_i \lambda_i
    = \operatorname{tr} f_i
    = |G| \langle \alpha, \chi_i \rangle
    = 0,
  $$
  it follows that $\lambda_i = 0$, and therefore that $f_i = 0$.

This proof sems to suggest that one should think about class functions as acting on representations, and that the inner product $\langle \alpha, \chi_V \rangle$ tells us something about how $\alpha$ (or more precisely $\beta$ with $\beta(g) = \alpha(g^{-1})$ ) acts on a representation $V$ (or maybe how $\alpha$ acts on $V^*$).
But so far I have not been able to make this idea more precise.

---

Comment: It is an open problem (that may well have no satisfactory answer) to find a "better" connection between the representations and the conjugacy classes, other than the fact that the numbers are the same. It would be amazing to somehow be able to associate a representation to each conjugacy class in a "natural" way, but this may well not be possible.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : For a positive answer, such connection exists for $G = S_n$ one can do such things, and also Springer correspondance is doing this for any Weyl group.

Comment: @N.H. Good point that these do exist for specific classes. But in some sense, the exact nature of the conjugacy class does not play much of a role, except that they happen to have an indexing set in common. Now, if one could somehow identify the conjugacy class from the two-sided cell corresponding to an irreducible representation (in type $A$), that would be interesting, but unfortunately the two-sided cells are not preserved by conjugation.

Comment: In fact, in a certain strong sense there is _not_ a natural bijection between irreducible representations and conjugacy classes.  Specifically, you can consider the isomorphism classes of irreducible representations of a group and the conjugacy classes of a  group both as functors from the category of finite groups and isomorphisms to the category of sets, and these functors are not naturally isomorphic.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21606/orbit-structures-of-conjugacy-class-set-and-irreducible-representation-set-under.